# Spyder debugger for Tensorflow

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow, spyder

Spyder comes with a powerful debugger which can be used to pause to code during execution and inspect the variables.

On the other hand, Tensorflow variables cannot be easily inspected. Is there a way to view them in python console in spyder?

Update:
While I was trying to answer the comment by anatoly techtonik, I decided to write a dummy program to show case the situation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class foo(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = tf.constant(a)
        self.b = tf.constant(b)
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        self.c = self._foo_add()
        # Launch the session
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        self.sess.run(init)

    def _foo_add(self):
        m = tf.add(self.a,self.b)
        return tf.add(m, tf.constant(1))

    def print_foo(self):
        return self.sess.run(self.c)

f = foo(2,3)
print f.print_foo()
```

If you put a checkpoint on the return statement of the function `_foo_add` , press the debug button and type `m.eval()` in the console, you can access its value which will be 5 in this case.
I guess that answers my question. Thanks anatoly techtonik.

Comment: For this to work, somebody needs to add special rendering for Tensorflow objects to object inspector.

Comment: Many objects cannot be seen in object inspector but it is possible to print their values in the debugger console.
Tensors on the other hand appear to be a little more tricky.

Comment: Can you post a gif of what's happening and how it should be? http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the tensorflow debugger

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/tfdbg

Coming with a MNIST tutorial

www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger

Alternative: Jupyter notebook seems to have a similar extension
(desiptes the project seems defunct)

https://github.com/ericjang/tdb